# ssh Permission denied // RPi 3 Model A+ macOS Mojave

Tags: ssh, connection, permissions, password, pi-3a+

I'm trying to access my RPi 3 Model A+ from my mac (Mojave) through ssh. They're both connected to a 5GHz wifi.

From the mac terminal, I type the RPi ip address, then the default password **raspberry** , but cannot move forward because:

**pi@192.168.0.11's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.**

The troubleshoots I tried so far:

- Connecting both of them to the 2.4GHz instead = still having the same problem.
- From the RPi terminal, I accessed the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file and uncommented **PasswordAuthentication Yes**
  but again no luck.

Any idea of what's going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Here's the output of the ssh -v:

```
Last login: Thu Apr  2 16:05:14 on ttys000
CBs-MacBook-Pro:~ ceciliabianchini$ ssh -v pi@192.168.0.11
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.11 [192.168.0.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.11:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3e5XiZCdd5PUNQIHcdvteGrEsEnq19VqV2rH4hgPf9A
debug1: Host '192.168.0.11' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.0.11's password:
```

Comment: Have you had another Pi or This Pi with an older image at this IP address before?  The log is stating that it knows this pi **Host '192.168.0.11' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.** simplest way may be to edit the Macs  known_hosts file with nano and remove line 1 - you will find this at /Users/ceciliabianchini/.ssh/known_hosts DO NOT use text edit in anything but text mode (nano is a lot simpler) and make a backup first :)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help! :) Just tried this, but didn't work. It brings me back to the initial message where it says "The authenticity of host '192.168.0.8 (192.168.0.8)' can't be established." I have to type yes to continue. 

I do yes, then type the pwd, and again permission denied. You can see from above that the IP address changed with ".8" meanwhile. I also tried to remove this last one from the known_hosts but same output.

I had another Pi which I burnt two weeks ago :S Maybe useful info? Thanks

Comment: Changing the file would have had zero effect on the remotes IP address - are you sure you are getting the correct IP address?  You may do better to use ssh pi@raspberrypi.local assuming you have not changed its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I `ssh` from my iMac to the Pi on a daily basis (although I long ago set private keys - so never use password).

macOS is quite properly objecting to a potential security breach.

This is fundamentally a macOS problem, but you can do a few things on the Pi to make it easier - and you should always do these anyway :-

1. Set a new password on the Pi - it should object if you don't anyway.
2. Give each Pi a **unique hostname** - this can be done in `raspi-config`

To explain the Mac stores the identity of the remote host (hostname and/or IP address) plus the public key of the host and checks this on each attempt. If you are using the same hostname on multiple Pi this triggers a security warning.

You can force the Mac to ignore with the following:-

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@192.168.0.11
```

This is OK for a test, but you should avoid overriding the security.

A couple of extra notes (which you probably don't want to know) - normally hosts have a unique key, but if you (like many Pi users) swap SD Cards between Pi this will also trigger a warning, because each Pi will have unique host keys.

I avoid all this malarky by setting public key pairs for the Pi and creating a `~/.ssh/config` on the Mac like:-

```
Host 10.1.*.*
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UseKeychain yes
   BatchMode yes
```

Some consider this a security violation, but if you limit to private IP on your home network this is OK (unless you have a family of hackers)

Comment: Amazing! I followed your steps (changed pwd and hostname) and it worked perfectly. Thanks also for all the explanation, very interesting indeed :)